# Cannot get my Java program to ask for input again

Tags: java

I am creating a small Rock, Paper, Scissors project to get into Java. I am a newcomer to the language. I've made it pretty far into my project, but I am stuck at a certain part. In the "Get Player Move" section, I want it to recognise if the player did or didn't input R, P, or S, and then ask for input again if needed. I have tried multiple ways to do this, but none worked properly. My code is below.

```
    {
Random generator = new Random ();

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


//Generate Random Computer Move
  computerAi = 0;
  computerAi = generator.nextInt(3)+1;

  if (computerAi == 3)
    computerMove = "S";
  else if (computerAi == 2)
    computerMove = "P";
  else if (computerAi == 1)
      computerMove = "R";

//Get Player Move

System.out.println("Enter R, P, or S. R= Rock, P= Paper, and S= Scissors: ");
  playerMove = in.nextLine();

//Display Choices
  System.out.println("You picked: " + playerMove);
  System.out.println("Computer Picked: " + computerMove);

//Determine if Player or Computer Won
if (playerMove.equals(computerMove))
  scoreCheck = 0;
else if (playerMove.equals("R"))
  if (computerMove.equals("P"))
    scoreCheck = -1;
  else if (computerMove.equals("S"))
    scoreCheck = 1;
else if (playerMove.equals("P"))
  if (computerMove.equals("S"))
    scoreCheck = -1;
  else if (computerMove.equals("R"))
    scoreCheck = 1;
else if (playerMove.equals("S"))
  if (computerMove.equals("R"))
    scoreCheck = -1;
  else if(computerMove.equals("P"))
    scoreCheck = 1;


//determine whether player won or lost
score += scoreCheck;
if (scoreCheck == 1)
  System.out.println("You Won! Score:" + score);

else if (scoreCheck == 0)
  System.out.println( "You Tied! Score:" + score);

else if (scoreCheck == -1)
  System.out.println("You Lost! Score:" + score);

System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("Type 'replay' to play again");
replay = in.nextLine();
scoreCheck = score;
}

}

}
```

I was able to access the original while statement I created for the project:

```
while (playerMove == ("None"))
44  - {
45  -   System.out.println("Enter R, P, or S. R= Rock, P= Paper, and S= Scissors: ");
46-     playerMove = in.nextLine();
47  - if (playerMove == ("R"))
48  -   System.out.println (" ");
4948     
50  - else if (playerMove == ("P"))
51  -   System.out.println (" ");
52  -
53  - else if (playerMove ==("S"))
54  -   System.out.println (" ");
55  -
56  - else if (playerMove != ("R"))
57  - {
58  -   if (playerMove != ("P"))
59  -   {
60  -    if (playerMove != ("S"))
61  -    {
62  -       System.out.println("Incorrect Input. Please try again.");
63  -       playerMove = "None";
64  -    }
65  -     else if (playerMove == ("S"))
66  -     
67  -   }
68  - }
69  - } 
}
```

Comment: Could you also add what you tried to get it to work? Did you use a while loop?

Comment: Nested ifs and elses without braces is asking for trouble.

Comment: @user I've tried a while loop, with multiple variations. In pseudo-code, it would pretty much be "while *boolean* equals 'true', repeat this code. if playerMove is equal to R, P, or S, move on. Otherwise, ask for new input and repeat." The problem is that no matter what the input, it always asks for new input. Not sure exactly how to circumvent this, as I've only been doing Java for a couple of weeks, and the internet hasn't been much work

Comment: It would be helpful to see the `while` statement itself.

Comment: @AndyThomas I don't have the original while statement, because I deleted it when it didn't work. I can give you something similar though. I will edit my question to show an approximation of the while statement I used.

Comment: The first thing which strikes into my eyes is a code. Please format the snippets when you post them here.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter R, P, or S. R= Rock, P= Paper, and S= Scissors: ");
playerMove = in.nextLine();
```

Change to something like:

```
String playerMove = null;
while (playerMove == null && !playerMove.matches("[rpsRPS]")) {
  System.out.println("Enter R, P, or S. R= Rock, P= Paper, and S= Scissors: ");
  playerMove = in.readline();

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for the most part, except for one problem I've been running into using this method. I have been getting this error message, and I'm not sure how to correct it:

 error: exception IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Comment: You can remove the try { } catch () {} and just leave the readline then.

Comment: @CNNR: Please remember to upvote and/or accept the answer if it solved your problem.